# Value of class object is lost when performing debug

Tags: angular

When I assign the value of an object to a variable "sumárioPessoaTemp" I can see the content of the variable, but then the value is lost and I can't see it anymore. I just put the console.log that I can.

There is an example in this video.
This is not the only scenario where the error occurs and was just an example of what happens.

Do you have any explanation for this?[image]

As shown in the video, in the first line when hovering the mouse over the variable "sumárioPessoaTemp" the content appears, but in the lines below the content disappears when they are being debugged.

This only happens in debugging time and the problem is only in the question of seeing the content of the variable. Other than that, there's no problem.

code snippet:

```
let sumarioPessoaTemp: SumarioPessoa[] = this.SumarioPessoaFormArray.getRawValue() as SumarioPessoa[];

// //select column values from array
let maiorOrdem: number = 0;
if (sumarioPessoaTemp != null && sumarioPessoaTemp.length > 0) {
  let ordem = sumarioPessoaTemp.map((t) => t.ordem);
  maiorOrdem = Math.max(...ordem);
}

maiorOrdem = maiorOrdem + 1;
```

Comment: Personnaly, I am not able to watch correctly your screen cast. The quality is not good.

Comment: @EmmanuelDemey Now it has better quality.